# Drupal - Conditional PHP if node is tagged with a certain taxonomy term

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

How can I write some conditional PHP to do something if a node is tagged with a certain term?

I want to alter my node-type.tpl.php file, this code is for the node page, not taxonomy listing pages.

Ideally id like to use the term's text name, not's its numeric name. This just makes it easier for me when im looking at the code later.

To be specific, I actually want to print some stuff unless the node has a certain tag.

Thanks

UPDATE

I got his code from the content template module:

```
<?php print $node->taxonomy[2]->name ?>
```

It prints the term name if the term ID is 2. So could it be modified to print something else if the term ID is 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with:

```
<?php if ($node->taxonomy[5]): ?> 
    print stuff here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks for your answers guys. They may well be more powerful solutions or better in some other way but they were beyond my knowledge to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  /*
   * You can change $variables items
   * or add own
   * Then use defined variables in node-type.tpl.php
   */
}
```

My own preprocess

```
/**
 * Override or insert PHPTemplate variables into the templates.
 */
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];

  if ($node->build_mode === NODE_BUILD_NORMAL || $node->build_mode === NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW) {
    $build_mode = $vars['teaser'] ? 'teaser' : 'full';
  }
  elseif ($node->build_mode === NODE_BUILD_RSS) {
    $build_mode = 'rss';
  }
  else {
    $build_mode = $node->build_mode;
  }
  $vars['template_files'][] = 'node--' . $build_mode;
  $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-' . $node->type . '-' . $build_mode;
  $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-' . $node->type . '-' . $build_mode . '-' . $node->nid;

  $preprocess = array(
      'report_preprocess_node_'  . $node->type,
      'report_preprocess_node__' . $build_mode,
      'report_preprocess_node_'  . $node->type . '_' . $build_mode,
      'report_preprocess_node_'  . $node->type . '_' . $build_mode . '_' . $node->nid
  );
  foreach (array_reverse($preprocess) as $function) {
    if (function_exists($function)) {
      $function($vars);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Im assuming the 2nd code goes in my template.php, where does the first code go? How can I then write conditional php on my node page? Thanks

Comment: This code for template.php
For ex.: $variables['my_var'] = 'foo';
In node-[type].tpl.php <?php print $my_var; ?>

Comment: Sorry, I still dont understand, Ive never done this level of theming before. So I add the both codes to my template.php, or just the 2nd? Then how do I define the taxonomy term as a variable so I can call it on my page?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to do this by creating a node-[type].tpl.php file in your theme. Using pure PHP, just check if the node has a particular taxonomy term and print some stuff out, or don't, as required.

You can customise /modules/node/node.tpl.php or node.tpl.php in your theme.

You may find [taxonomy_node_get_terms](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_get_terms/6) and [taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary/6) to be useful.

Comment: Im already using a node-[type].tpl.php, but how do I check the taxonomy term with php? Ive found lots or articles on how to recognize the taxonomy term if the node is on the term's page, but I dont know how to get tagged terms from the node's page. Thanks

Comment: I have updated my answer with some drupal api functions you can use to get the taxonomy terms for a node.

Comment: The 2nd link sounds promising as the description is 'Find all terms associated with the given node, within one vocabulary' but how do I use this code? The first post 'Example using this hook' prints text dependent on what vocabularies are used, but instead I need to print something if a term is used. Thanks

Comment: Well you have access to the $node object within the template, so you can call `taxonomy_node_get_terms($node->nid);` to get a list of all the terms, for example. Use `print_r` to inspect these objects or `dsm` if you have the devel module enabled.

Comment: Ive heard of this sort of method before and I kind of understand the theory but its a bit beyond me. Using content template module Ive found the following code prints the term name if its id is 2. Could I change the code to print something if the term id is 2?: <?php print $node->taxonomy[2]->name ?>    Thanks

Comment: `<?php if(in_array(2, taxonomy_node_get_terms($node->nid))) { // do something } ?>`

Answer (score 0):

In template.php

```
function phptemplate_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  $node = $variables['node'];
  $taxonomy = $node->taxonomy;

  $items = array();
  foreach($taxonomy AS $term){
    $items[] = l($term->name, taxonomy_term_path($term));
  }
  $variables['my_term_links'] = theme_item_list($items);
}
```

In node-[type].tpl.php

```
print $my_term_links;
```